# Disabled finder button - SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, external-list

I have an `external list` available in SharePoint Designer. Now I try to edit my list.

I can't figure out why finder button (`refer below screen shot`) is still disabled. I'm sure that button should be available only for external list.

[image: designer]

Answer (score 0):

This link may be useful for you to debug this issue - [Creating External Lists: Tips and Warnings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee556424(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: Problem occurred on production environment. I have exactly same configuration on development environment where button is available. Maybe I miss some permissions?